# Extend Combobox with Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I want to extend the WPF Combobox in a way that two buttons are displayed next to the combobox. I cannot use a UserControl, because I need to specify the items of the combobox in pure xaml like this:

```
<CustomComboBox>
   <CustomComboBoxItem />
   <CustomComboBoxItem />
</CustomComboBox>
```

I'm quite scared to take the template of the combobox and extend it, because for comboboxes it is very large and complex. I'm looking for an easy and simple solution to create that kind of ComboBox-like `ItemsControl` with just two buttons attached to it. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: If UserControl isn't good and it is impossible to just copy-paste these 2 buttons - a custom control is only one way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Conrete example using a `UserControl`:

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.CustomComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox Name="_comboBox" Margin="5"/>
        <Button Content="_Apply" Padding="3"  Margin="5" Click="Button_Apply_Click"/>
        <Button Content="_Reset" Padding="3"  Margin="5" Click="Button_Reset_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public partial class CustomComboBox : UserControl
{
    public event RoutedEventHandler ApplyClick;
    public event RoutedEventHandler ResetClick;

    public ItemCollection Items
    {
        get { return _comboBox.Items; }
        set
        {
            _comboBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                _comboBox.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Apply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ApplyClick != null)
        {
            ApplyClick(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ResetClick != null)
        {
            ResetClick(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 <local:CustomComboBox ApplyClick="Button2_Click">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
 </local:CustomComboBox>
```

Appearance:

[image]

---

A UserControl should do fine, you can still specify the items in Xaml markup, e.g. if i have a time user control i can do this:

```
[ContentProperty("Hours")]
public partial class TimeBox : UserControl
{
    public string Hours
    {
        get { return this.TBHours.Text; }
        set { this.TBHours.Text = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

That way you can set the hours in XAML:

```
        <local:TimeBox>
            <sys:String>24</sys:String>
        </local:TimeBox>
```

You should be able to adapt this to set the items of your ComboBox.

Comment: This can be done with Controls which have a ContentPresenter. It won't work for ItemsControls.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, i updated my answer with a working example...

Comment: I admit that works, but I can't provide a x:Name Attribute for the ComboBoxItems using this approach. :(

Comment: Right, but maybe there is a better design alternative to naming the items because in WPF you normally can get things done without naming the vast majority of controls because of data binding.

Comment: I need the names because the Security System is dependent on them. It adjusts the views depending on the user's privileges. Every single item in our application has a name and can be referenced, so we have a flexible GUI configuration if some users are not allowed to see certain buttons etc.

Comment: And by item, I really mean control. Every single control is named in the app and we have approx. 50k lines or markup.

Comment: Not really, in fact, it's a really great, configurable and powerful system. There're various ways to reference the controls and that's why we are dependent on names.